# How can I clean the list of "Open Recent" files?

Tags: texstudio

The files in the "File -> Open Recent" list are updated automatically when I open new files, except that files that were "Master Documents" at some point, remain on the top of the list indefinitely:

[image]

How can I remove these files from the list?

Comment: I am almost sure that you can delete the entries in the texstudio.ini file. There is the line with `Files\Recent%20Files` and you can see the list of files. So, with TeXstudio closed, delete that line, save the ini file and then open the TeXstudio.

Comment: @Sigur where can I find this `ini` file?

Comment: Are you using Linux?